# How does one manually place \thanks text?

Tags: beamer, footnotes, beamerposter, titling

I'm using beamerposter with the confpresentation style to create a poster. I want to include the author email addresses in the header along with the department, and I want to do it `\thanks`-style.

However, when I use `\thanks`, [it starts the footnote counter at 2 and the footnote text doesn't get placed anywhere](https://gist.github.com/mohawkjohn/edc966547fe272bebf77). I can override the footnote symbols without too much difficulty, hiding this problem, but I'm not really sure why it's happening.

I tried using the `titling` package, but it seems to be incompatible with beamer.

I've also tried searching Google for information about the thanks command, but with thanks being such a common word, it's incredibly difficult to find documentation on it. Is there a way to manually place thanks text in a document?

That's my real question, but I'd also accept an answer that clarifies the issues with beamer and thanks.

Comment: Sounds weird, MWE please?

Comment: @Symbol1 Sure, included in the question, and also here: https://gist.github.com/mohawkjohn/edc966547fe272bebf77

Answer (score 1):

In general it is not very hard to insert the content of `thanks`, this can be done with `\@thanks`. As you cannot use @ in a normal beamer frame, you can hide it in a new command:

```
\documentclass{beamer} 

\title[MWE]{MWE poster title}
\subtitle{A minimum working example}
\author[Woods \& Christian]{John~O.~Woods, Ph.D.;\thanks{test.email@wvu.edu} Andrew~Rhodes; Jordan~L.~Sell; and John~A.~Christian, Ph.D.}
\institute[West Virginia University]{Department of Mechanical and Aerospace Engineering, West Virginia University}
\date{\today}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\insertthanks}{\@thanks}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \insertauthor

    \insertthanks
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

However this will not play nicely with your MWE, as you use `beamerposter` which has problems with placing footnotes on the first page. Probably you don't need `beamerposter`, there are other ways to change papersize etc.

The numbering issue is due to multiple usage of the title, test the following example and you will understand how every usage of the title adds its own thanks.

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer} 

\title[MWE]{MWE poster title}
\subtitle{A minimum working example}
\author[Woods \& Christian]{John~O.~Woods, Ph.D.;\thanks{test.email@wvu.edu} Andrew~Rhodes; Jordan~L.~Sell; and John~A.~Christian, Ph.D.}
\institute[West Virginia University]{Department of Mechanical and Aerospace Engineering, West Virginia University}
\date{\today}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\insertthanks}{\@thanks}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \insertauthor
    \insertauthor

    \insertthanks
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```